Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z unresolved
I have looked through answers for similar issues and none have resolved the issue I'm having. Some hadoop commands seem to work (example hadoop fs -cat) while others not (hadoop fs -ls, which threw this error)
I have my path variable setup


and winutils even appears to be found

I also have hadoop.dll in the very same directory and in my Windows/System32 folder and it still doesn't seem to work after restarting my machine.

Truly a head scratcher here because I would not have expected partial functionality if something was broken
Hadoop version is 3.3.6
Java is version "1.8.0_202"
Spark is 3.5.3

I don't think this has anything to do with [tag:PowerShell]. What happens when you run it from the cmd prompt?

@iRon that's totally possible. I tried to think what was different about my set up and previous and one thing that occurred to me that there could be a difference between CMD and powershell. It does in fact throw the same error so I can remove that tag if need be

I changed my version of Hadoop to 3.2.2 and it now works, but tbh I have no idea why
It seems like a lot of Hadoop is poorly documented and I'm not sure where I could have read up on a versioning issue (assuming that's what it was) other than going about this through trial and error like I did

Hadoop is designed to work on Linux, mostly. That might be why you'd find it poorly documented. The DLL file is version of specific, which is why downgrading could work. It's also recommended to use Java 11 as 8 is end of life

@OneCricketeer if it were up to me, many versions of many of the applications I'm using would be much newer. Alas, my school makes the rules here lol

My school had us use pre built VMs, rather than install everything ourselves ;)
